# Transformation in $SO(4)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-groups, quaternions

I want to prove that for any unitary $q,q'\in \mathbb{H}$:
$$T_{q,q'}:\mathbb{H}\rightarrow \mathbb{H}$$
$$x\mapsto qxq'$$
belongs to $SO(4)$. Is there any elegant way to show it without expanding this product in terms of coordinates?

Answer (score 4):

One can define (a group isomorphic to) $O(4)$ as the $\mathbb{R}$-linear transformations $\mathbb{H}\to\mathbb{H}$ which preserve the inner product $\langle q,q'\rangle:=\operatorname{Re}(\overline{q}q')$. $SO(4)$ is then the subgroup of these transformations which are orientation preserving (or, equivalently, continuously connected to the identity). Presumably this is what you refer to when asking if a transformation is "in" $SO(4)$.

From there, one can show that the left multiplication maps $L_q(q'):=qq'$ and the right multiplication maps $R_q(q'):=q'q$ are $\mathbb{R}$-linear and preserve the inner product, and thus elements of $O(4)$. Since both the right translations and left translations are connected groups, they are in fact contained in $SO(4)$. Thus, any composition of these maps will also be an element of $SO(4)$.

Comment: Very minor point:  this is an outline of a proof that you get something "in" $O(4)$.  The simplest way I know of showing it's in $SO(4)$ is a connectedness argument.

Comment: @JasonDeVito Right. I somehow managed to forget that subtlety.